# BigCommerce - Hide the 'add to cart' for a product based on customer group?

Tags: bigcommerce

I am building a BigCommerce site for a client who is splitting his customer groups into Wholesalers and Retail. Some of the Wholesale products can't be sold to Retail clients, but he still wants them to be visible to the Retail clients so to encourage them to move to a Wholesale account.

Can I hide the 'Add to Cart' button in BigCommerce based on the Customer Group? I'm guessing I can do this with an IF statement but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend using the {{#unless}} block helper instead of {{#if}}:

```
{{#unless customer.customer_group_name '===' 'Wholesale'}}
<style>
CSS to hide the add to cart button
</style>
{{/unless}}
```

The display:none on the cart button will be active unless the customer is logged into a Wholesale account (note that the customer group name will need to match the customer group name in your store exactly--it will be case sensitive). You could also use customer.customer_group_id if you know the id of the wholesale customer group.

Comment: That's awesome thanks, do you think I could also base this on the category that the product is in?

Comment: Sure--if you need to check for multiple conditions, you can nest block helpers. You can check for category.name or category.id